# How to create 3d model to display for online use

Tags: html, model, minecraft

So this question may seem hard to understand and very vague and that's because I have no other way of explaining this, so I'll try and describe what I want to achieve.

So essentially I want to create a character model (based from the protagonist of Minecraft, Steve). What I'd like this to serve as is a texture viewer from which a user enters his username into. A site that does is can be found [here](http://mcapi.ca/pages/docs/skin)

See how the texture is displayed by a 3d blocky character? That is what I want to create, so essentially a blank 3d model where users textures will appear on when entered.

I'm not asking for entire code on this, I just need to some guidance as to how I would go about doing this. 
Thanks for any and all help! If you got more questions I will try and answer them as best as I can. Thanks again!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, doesn't that site give you exactly what you need? The API returns an image of the model with the skin that the selected player has. So for the character "John", you'd use the URL `https://mcapi.ca/skin/3d/John`.

Comment: @Rein S Yes, I wish to create my own model to display the texture on. The site was merely a demonstration as to what I want to create. Sorry, I should have made this much clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, whenever trying to implement some graphics-related feature boils down to working with svg, or canvas, or just plain images. I would recommend that you look into using the HTML5 canvas element with maybe WebGL.